# Finding the number of subsets of a set such that an element divides the succeeding element.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, puzzle

[image]

Hello everybody! The problem you see above is a combinatorial problem that I could not solve. :(

Since we are to choose distinct numbers from $\{1,2,3 \ldots K\}$, the numbers must be in increasing order because they are all positive. I think that the difficulty of this problem is in the fact that the *Special Sequence* can be of any length. We can go about choosing say $n$ elements in $\binom{K}{n}$ ways but again how do we control that? Talking about a recursive solution, I think that is the way to go but I can't get how to do that (that is get a recursive formula for that).

Any help in solving this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Find the number of special sequences of length one. Then find the number with length two. Then length three. And so on. Alternatively, your idea of using recursion is good. E.g., for $K=19$, the only special sequences that use $19$ are $(19)$ and $(1,19)$, so just two more than the answer for $K=18$. But relating the number for $K=18$ to that for $K=17$ will be trickier.

Comment: maximum length is $\lceil log_2(K)\rceil$ only if it contains 1.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We denote with $a[n],  n\geq 1$ the number of special sequences  and with $b[n], n\geq  1$ the number of special sequences where each element contains $n$ as greatest element. We     observe $a[n]$ contains all special    sequences of $a[n-1]$  together   with all special sequences $b[n],       (n>1)$.

> We have
>   \begin{align*}
> &a[1]=b[1]=\left|\{(1)\}\right|=1\\
> &a[n]=a[n-1]+b[n ]  \qquad\qquad n>   1
> \end{align*}

In  order to  find $b[n]$ we need  to  analyse the prime factor decomposition of $n$. We create a  small knowledge base of numbers which  we need to factorise $K=1,\ldots,22$.

Let  $p,q$  be  primes. We obtain
\begin{align*}
b[p]&=\left|\{(p),(1,p)\}\right|=2\\
b[p^2]&=\left|\{(p^2),(1,p^2),(p,p^2),(1,p,p^2)\}\right|=4\\
b[p^3]&=\left|\{(p^3),(1,p^3),(p,p^3),(p^2,p^3),(1,p,p^3),(1,p^2,p^3),(1,p,p^2,p^3)\}\right|=8\\
b[p^4]&=2^4=16\\
b[pq]&=\left|\{(pq),(1,pq),(p,pq),(q,pq),(1,p,pq),(1,q,pq)\}\right|=6\\
b[p^2q]&=\left|\{(p^2q),(1,p^2q),(p,p^2q),(q,p^2q),(p^2,p^2q),(pq,p^2q),\right.\\
&\qquad(1,p,p^2q),(1,q,p^2q),(1,p^2,p^2q),(1,pq,p^2q),\\
&\qquad(p,p^2,p^2q),(p,pq,p^2q),(q,pq,p^2q),\\
&\qquad\left.(1,p,p^2,p^2q),(1,p,pq,p^2q),(1,q,pq,p^2q))\}\right|=16\\
\end{align*}

> Now it's time to harvest. We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a[15]}&=a[14]+b[13]=a[13]+b[12]+b[13]\\
> &=a[1]+\sum_{j=2}^{13}b[j]\\
> &=1+\sum_{j\in\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}}b[j]+\sum_{j\in\{4,9\}}b[j]+\sum_{j\in\{6,10,14,15\}}b[j]+b[8]+b[12]\\
> &=1+6b[p]+2b[p^2]+4b[pq]+b[p^3]+b[p^2q]\\
> &=1+12+8+24+8+16\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=69}\\
> \color{blue}{a[19]}&=a[15]+b[16]+b[17]+b[18]+b[19]\\
> &=69+b[2^4]+b[17]+b[3^2\cdot 2]+b[19]\\
> &=69+b[p^4]+2b[p]+b[p^2q]\\
> &=69+16+4+16\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=105}\\
> \color{blue}{a[22]}&=a[19]+b[20]+b[21]+b[22]\\
> &=105+b[2^2\cdot5]+b[3\cdot7]+b[2\cdot11]\\
> &=105+b[p^2q]+2b[pq]\\
> &=105+16+12\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=133}\\
> \end{align*}

*Note:* Interestingly, the sequence $\left(a[n]\right)_{n\geq 1}=(1,3,5,9,11,17,19,27,31,\ldots)$ doesn't    seem  to  be  archived in *[OEIS](https://oeis.org/)*, but the sequence $\left(b[n]\right)_{n\geq1}=(1,2,2,4,2,6,2,8,4,6,2,16,2,\ldots)$ is archived in OEIS as *[A067824](https://oeis.org/A067824)*.

Comment: Program output $(1,3,5,9,11,17,19,27,31,37,39,55,57,63,\color{blue}{69},85,87,103,\color{blue}{105},121,127,\color{blue}{133},135,175)$ disagrees with your results.

Comment: @DanielMathias: Thanks a lot for pointing at the mistake. I've missed four cases at $b[p^2q]$. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you Markus for the brilliant solution!

Comment: I just want to know how did you think of this solution? The solution is clear and easy to understand, but how might have I come up with this solution on my own? Also, how can I be sure to not have made any errors in all these computations?

Comment: Many thanks for your nice comment. I started with small numbers and drew Hasse diagrams which are useful when looking at divisibility aspects and their partial ordering. This way I also recognized the recurrence relation between a[n] and b[n]. To not calculate each case from 1 to 22 it's a matter of experience to use some kind of repertoire method and reduce this way calculations. – Markus Scheuer 6 mins ago

Comment: Thank you Markus! I just wanted to ask if there is a way to not count them manually as I am making a lot of mistakes counting $b[pq]$ and $b[p^2q]$ manually?

Comment: @Vasu090: I recommend drawing a Hasse diagram, which might be helpful in order to not forget any cases. We can order them lexicographically and check for symmetries, which gives a kind of plausibility check. Here we also know the number $b[n]$ due to the given OEIS sequence. If the OEIS sequence is not known, we can instead try to solve the combinatorial problem of finding $b[n]$ in advance, which is interesting by itself. We might also try to write a small program, which generates all cases.