# What is wrong with my approach in recurrence?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

A sequence of positive integers,a[1], a[2], a[3], . . . , a[n] is called a Special Sequence,i fa[1]  divides a[2],a[2]  divides a[3],  and  so  on  until a[n−1]  divides a[n],  and  if all the elements are distinct.  For example, (2,4,8,32) is a Special Sequence.  But(4,2,8) is not, because 4 does not divide 2.  Similarly (2,4,4,8) is also not Special,because the elements are not distinct.You need to find the find the number of special sequence for element sequence from set {1,2,3.......2K+1}.
**My approach:**  Let $a_{2k+1}$ be the number of ways this could be done. Based on whether 2 is selected or not, I found the recursion formula to be:
$a_{2k+1}= a_{k}+ 1 +  a_{2k}$, First for when only even numbers could be selected with it and 1, and other for selection of other 2k elements. However,the correct answer for k=7, i.e. 69 doesn't come and the correct answer for k=9,i.e.105 doesn't come either.What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421396)

Comment: *Based on whether 2 is selected or not, I found the recursion formula to be:*
$_{2+1}=_{+1}+_{2}$.  This needs to be explained because it's not clear how this is connected to the number of special sequences.  I would guess that is where your mistake is.