# A sequence of positive integers, a[1], a[2], a[3], . . . , a[n] is called a Special Sequence...[Read full Q. Below]

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, contest-math

A sequence of positive integers, a[1], a[2], a[3], . . . , a[n] is called a Special Sequence, if a[1] divides a[2], a[2] divides a[3], and so on until a[n−1] divides a[n], and if all the elements are distinct. For example, (2, 4, 8, 32) is a Special Sequence. But (4, 2, 8) is not, because 4 does not divide 2. Similarly (2, 4, 4, 8) is also not Special, because the elements are not distinct.

You need to find the number of Special Sequences such that all the elements of the sequence are from the set {1, 2, . . . , K}.

Suppose K = 3. The Special Sequences possible are (1), (2), (3), (1, 2), (1, 3). So
the answer would be 5.

Find the answer for K = 19.

**My Approach**

Core Concept: {a, b} and {b, c} are two special sequence sets, then so will be {a, b, c}

I can use this and solve the cardinality for every number up to 19 and that would give me the answer but it takes too much manual effort so I think there is another way to do this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428614/what-is-wrong-with-my-approach-in-recurrence which leads you to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421396/finding-the-number-of-subsets-of-a-set-such-that-an-element-divides-the-succeedi

Comment: Hint: what do you know about that is related to divisibility?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get you